# sending a $_SESSION array to my class and attempting to get the value fro it in a for loop .php

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

i have a class which in which iam using a method to get information from a session array via a for loop the 2 for loops in each method are used 1.to count total amount of items , and 2. to add up the total price but neither seem to be returning anything. im using the total amount to check it against the mc_gross posted value from an IPN and if the values are equal i plan to commit the sale to a database as it has been verified. for the method where im looking to get the total price im getting 0.00 returned to me. i think ive got the syntax wrong here somehow here is my class for purchase the two methods iam having trouble with are the gettotalcost() and gettotalitems() shown below is my class.

```
<?php


class purchase {

private $itemnames;     // from session array
private $amountofitems; // from session array
private $itemcost;     //session array
private $saleid;        //posted transaction id value to be used in sale and sale item     tables
private $orderdate;   //get current date time to be entered as datetime in sale table
private $lastname;   //posted from ipn
private $firstname;   //posted from ipn
private $emailadd;   //uses sessionarray value


public function __construct($saleid,$firstname,$lastname)
{
    $this->itemnames = $_SESSION['itemnames'];
    $this->amountofitems =$_SESSION['quantity'];
    $this->itemcost =$_SESSION['price'];
    $this->saleid = $saleid;
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->lastname = $lastname;
    $this->emailadd = $SESSION['username'];
    mail($myemail, "session vardump ",  echo var_dump($_SESSION), "From: you@youremail.com" );
 mail($myemail, "session vardump ",count($_SESSION['itemnames']) , "From: you@youremail.com" );
}

     public function commit()
 {

   $databaseinst = database::getinstance();
   $databaseinst->connect();

   $numrows = $databaseinst->querydb($query);
   //to be completed
 }




 public function gettotalitems()
  {
      $numitems;
      $i;

      for($i=0; $i < count($this->amountofitems);$i++)
      {
          $numitems += (int) $this->amountofitems[$i];

      }

     return $numitems;
  }


 public function gettotalcost()
  {
      $totalcost;
      $i;


      for($i=0; $i < count($this->amountofitems);$i++)
      {
          $numitems = (int) $this->amountofitems[$i];
          $costofitem =doubleval($this->itemcost [$i]);
          $totalcost += $numitems * $costofitem;
      }


     return  $totalcost;
  }   







}

?>
```

and here is where i create an instance of the class and attempt to use it.

include("purchase.php");

```
$purchase = new purchase($_POST['txn_id'],$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name']);


$fullamount = $purchase->gettotalcost();
$fullAmount = number_format($fullAmount, 2);
$grossAmount = $_POST['mc_gross']; 


if ($fullAmount != $grossAmount) {


$message = "Possible Price Jack attempt! the amount the customer payed is : " .   $grossAmount . 
"  which is not equal to the full amount. the price of the products combined is " . $fullAmount. " 
      the transaction number for which is " . $_POST['txn_id']  .    "\n\n\n$req";
    mail("XXXXXXXXXXXX", "Price Jack attempt ", $message, "From: you@youremail.com" );
    exit(); // exit 

   }
```

thanks for the help in advance!

ive also added these lines to my constructor. the mail returns that there is nothing in the vardump uh oh!

```
   mail($myemailaddress, "session vardump ", var_dump($_SESSION), "From:   you@youremail.com" );
```

also added
                      session_start();

at the top of the constructor and it dont work! help
alright i gotr vardump printing out on a seperate php page and it gives me this.

array(9) { ["token"]=> string(32) "964885a70512d21933d139663a8fe48a" ["ID"]=> string(19) "XXXXXXXX" ["username"]=> string(19) "XXXXXX" ["password"]=> string(5) "XXX" ["admin"]=> string(1) "0" ["set"]=> string(4) "true" ["itemnames"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(43) "Cape Clear Island :Its People and Landscape" [1]=> string(30) "Naomh Ciaran: Pilgrim Islander" [2]=> string(35) "O Driscolls:Past and Present (2005)" } ["quantity"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" } ["price"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "12.73" [1]=> string(5) "23.99" [2]=> string(5) "11.76" } }

Comment: are you sure that at the time of creating the class the $_SESSION values are setted properly and the session has started?

Comment: why have you written "$totalcost;$i;" and "$numitems;$i;" explicitly in the functions?

Comment: @OM The Eternity hats just the way im used to doing it in java.

Comment: with this  "count($this->amountofitems)" im attempting to just count the number of items in the array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright here is the answer , the IPN wont deal with the session variables as i travel away from my site to process the transactions, so i have to persist them to my database then if all checks pass in my IPN script i can mark the transaction as payed in my database using a unique transaction number which i will create as a custom variable that  i will pass to paypal. if the checks fail i will mail() the person buying the goods and delete them using the same unique transaction number that i will get back fro paypal as an ipn custom variable. wow stackoverflow is usually a better help than this, maybe my question was a bit too vague!

Answer (score 0):

You must start the session as `session_start();` before anything

Try to print the numitems and totalcost variables in there functions itself to debug...

Comment: the session arrays are all created and working properly as i use them to populate my shopping cart.

Comment: do i have to start the session inside in the class if it is already created?

Comment: before instantiating the object of any class and to use the sessions in the same class,u should get the session started

Comment: @eoin can you add an var_dump($_SESSION); in the constructor and paste the output here?

Comment: ill print it to a file! it will take me a few minutes to do

Comment: actually ill just mail the vardump to myself and then ill post it here

Comment: mail($myemailaddress, "session vardump ", var_dump($_SESSION), "From: you@youremail.com" );

Comment: also added session_start();  at the top of the constructor and it dont work! help!

Comment: it is mailing to me soi it is at least going into the constructor! im stumped with this one!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
 include("purchase.php");

 var_dump($_SESSION)

 exit;

 $purchase = new purchase($...........
?>
```

try and check what are the dump values to make sure you have valid session

Comment: alright ill try and do that now. i took a break a minute ago, now the mails that i placed in the constructor arent sending to me this is getting really annoying

Comment: im comming back to the page after leaving to do some processing on the paypal site! this could be the problem! should i call session_start in the constructor and the script?!

Comment: or could it be because the IPN is running while im on the paypal page and that wont give back session variables to my object

Comment: need help here i also fixed the syntax errors on the names of the variables

Comment: you need to invoke session_start before using session variable . It could be anywhere , but before using the session data